# why I got unexpected EOF Error file creating react native app

Tags: ubuntu, react-native

I am trying to create a react-native app using expo init command in ubuntu 16. but I got the following error

```
[22:54:46] Extracting project files...

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Process exited with non-zero code: 2
[22:54:46] zlib: unexpected end of file
[22:54:46] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

what should I do

Comment: Question was cross-posted to Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1090562/301745

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code, add something where you check for the EOF and then skip over it so it doesn't give you an error. This sort of thing happened in some of my code once too.

Comment: how can I do that? because  I am not so much familiar with ubuntu

Comment: I'm not sure, I am not familiar with ubuntu either, but I know that you should do something like that. Maybe search for that question or make a question for that and someone else might answer it. Sorry if I didn't help.